# How actually RTMP work

Tags: streaming, rtmp

I'm not a video expert but what I understand about RTMP that it work in the following manner :

**Video Source -> MP4 Container -> FLV Container -> RTMP Container -> Propagate through internet -> RTMP Server**

I'm an android developer and I need to create a program which can take frames from device camera and transmit them to RTMP server. 
For this first I need to understand how actually RTMP works.

Can someone please explain what should I do with the RAW camera frames and how should I prepare them to propagate through RTMP channel.

I'm using wowza server for this setup.
I just need the workflow no need of code (I'll be great if you can provide :) ).

Thanks